# Magento 2.1: How to use getParam('param') function for this case?

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers

I have this page: [magento2.emthemes.com/everything/women/tops-women.html].

 
When i click on the fillter on the left i will get this link:[magento2.emthemes.com/everything/women/tops-women.html?cat=2‌​3] . It has **param_value = tops-women.html**, **query_string_name=cat**, **query_string_value=23**. In generality, what is the **param_value** for that?

**Example:** I have code into Controller, in this case **param_value=data** (`$data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data');`):


 
`class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();`

```
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data');
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $result = array();
    if($data){
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
        $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock($result['type']);
        $block->setData('current_url',$data->current_url);
        if(!$this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('formkey')){
            $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey','formkey');
        }
        //echo "<pre>";echo $block->toHtml();die;   
        $block->setData($result);   
        $block->setData('uniqueId',uniqid());
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
}
```

`}`

Comment: @Atish Goswami: I have created a new question.

Comment: use $this->getRequest()->getParam('cat')

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this

$cat = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cat');

Comment: Thanks. I mean in generality, i want to fetch value for this link: http://magento2.emthemes.com/everything/women/tops-women.html?cat=2‌​3. In PHP, i have mysql_fetch_array, how to use in Magento 2. How to define into Controller Magento 2.

Comment: You want to get the value of cat in your controller right?

Comment: Yep, could you help me, please? Thanks

Comment: You can get it by using the mentioned code in my answer.